# login with active directory users on debian jessy not working

Tags: active-directory, debian, samba, kerberos, pam

I'm trying to get the login with active directory users working for nearly a week now. First of all, I'm pretty new to pam, samba, kerberos and winbind. We worked with local users and sudo before, but decided to use active directory for user authenticationm so we don't have to maintain the AD and the local users on every machine. I googled and found a handful of quiet similar documentation on how to accomplish this.

First of all, I setup a testbox with Debian Jessie. The second step was to install these packages. In braces are the purposes as I understood them, correct me please, if I'm wrong:

```
• krb5-user (Kerberos client, for recieving TGT and user authentication)
• samba (Samba for joining the AD with the Linux-box)
• smbclient (mounting the home-directory)
• winbind (second way of user-authentication, if Kerberos fails for any reason)
• libpam-winbind (PA-Module for winbind)
• libpam-mount (Not sure about this one)
• libpam-ccreds (Storing credentials, if the DC is not reachable)
• libpam-krb5 (PAM-Module for Kerberos)
• cifs-utils (Mounting cif shares)
```

I am able to join the domain with this command:

```
net ads join member -k -S DC1.DOMAIN.LOCAL -U {User_with_admin_rights} createcomputer=IT/BLA osName=Debian osVer=`cat /etc/debian_version` -d 1
```

After succesfully joining the AD it's pussibble to get a Kerberos TGT:

```
kinit -V user@DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

And get a listing:

```
root@testbox / % klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user@DOMAIN.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
14.12.2015 09:47:01  14.12.2015 19:47:01 krbtgt/DOMAIN.LOCAL@DOMAIN.LOCAL
renew until 15.12.2015 09:46:57
```

But when I try to login with an AD-user (username: username@DOMAIN.LOCAL) it won't work:

```
Dec 14 13:19:58 testbox login[2875]: pam_krb5(login:auth): user username@DOMAIN.LOCAL authenticated as username@DOMAIN.LOCAL
Dec 14 13:20:01 testbox login[2875]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/pts/2' FOR 'UNKNOWN', User not known to the underlying authentication module
```

As far as I understand it, the username can be authenticated via Kerberos, but this information is not sent to the next module, am I right?

Rearding the pam-configuration, I just did a pam-auth-update and activeted everything:

```
[*] Kerberos authentication
[*] Ccreds credential caching - password saving
[*] Unix authentication
[*] Winbind NT/Active Directory authentication
[*] Mount volumes for user
[*] Ccreds credential caching - password checking
```

And restarted the services (smbd, winbind) afterwards.

The name resolution of the DCs is working in both ways on the linuxbox.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Here's my /etc/krb5.conf (I removed the comments):

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = DOMAIN

krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
kdc_timesync = 1
ccache_type = 4
forwardable = true
proxiable = true

v4_instance_resolve = false
v4_name_convert = {
    host = {
        rcmd = host
        ftp = ftp
    }
    plain = {
        something = something-else
    }
}
fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
DOMAIN.LOCAL = {
    kdc = DC1.domain.local
    kdc = DC2.domain.local
    kdc = DC.domain.local
    kdc = DC4.domain.local
    kdc = DC5.domain.local
    admin_server = DC1.domain.local
    default_domain = domain
}

[domain_realm]
   kerberos.server = DOMAIN.LOCAL

[login]
   krb4_convert = true
krb4_get_tickets = false

[logging]
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/krb5/kadmind.log
    default = SYSLOG:NOTICE:DAEMON
```

This is my smb.conf:

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================
[global]
security = ADS
encrypt passwords = yes
realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
winbind enum users = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind use default domain = yes
winbind refresh tickets = yes
template homedir = /home/%D/%U
template shell = /bin/bash
client use spnego = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = yes
encrypt passwords = yes
restrict anonymous = 2
domain master = no
local master = no
preferred master = no
os level = 0

workgroup = DOMAIN

;   wins server = w.x.y.z
dns proxy = no
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
#####
server role = standalone server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
########
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
;   logon drive = H:
;   logon script = logon.cmd
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machineaccount" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
##########
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash
;   usershare max shares = 100
usershare allow guests = yes
#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700
valid users = %S

;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700
```

And last, but not least, the nsswitch.conf:
    passwd:         compat winbind
    group:          compat winbind
    shadow:         compat winbind
    gshadow:        files

```
hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got it working by myself, at least the login. Testet the idmapping on two diefferent boxes and uid & gid are on both the same. The only thing, that's not working atm is the mounting of the home directory as set in the Unix-tab of the user in the Active Directory settings. As a workaround a directory is created under /home/*domainname*/*username*. I'll post my configs here and, when I get the mounting of the "AD-home-directory" working, an update, off course.

smb.conf:

```
    [global]

workgroup = DOMAIN
security = ADS
realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
netbios name = HOSTNAME
dedicated keytab file = /etc/krb5.keytab
kerberos method = secrets and keytab

idmap config DOMAIN : default = yes
idmap config DOMAIN : backend = ad
idmap config DOMAIN : schema_mode = rfc2307
idmap config DOMAIN : readonly = yes
idmap config DOMAIN : range = 10000-1999999
idmap cache time = 604800

 template homedir = /home/%D/%U
 template shell = /bin/bash

winbind trusted domains only = no
winbind use default domain = yes
winbind enum users = no
winbind enum groups = no
winbind refresh tickets = yes
winbind expand groups = 4
winbind offline logon = true
winbind nss info = rfc2307

domain master = no
local master = no
vfs objects = acl_xattr
map acl inherit = yes
store dos attributes = yes
client ldap sasl wrapping = sign
encrypt passwords = yes

client use spnego = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = yes
restrict anonymous = 2
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = member server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
```

krb5.conf

[libdefaults]
        default_realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
        krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
        krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true
        default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab

```
    v4_instance_resolve = false
    v4_name_convert = {
        host = {
            rcmd = host
            ftp = ftp
        }
        plain = {
            something = something-else
        }
    }
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
    DOMAIN.LOCAL = {
        kdc = DC1.DOMAIN.local
        admin_server = DC1.DOMAIN.local
        default_domain = DOMAIN.local
    }

[domain_realm]
    .DOMAIN.local = DOMAIN.LOCAL
    DOMAIN.local = DOMAIN.LOCAL

[login]
    krb4_convert = true
    krb4_get_tickets = false

[logging]
        default = SYSLOG:DEBUG:DAEMON
```

The nsswitch hasn't changed. If there are any suggestions or hints on how to get the mounting of the other home directory working, I'll really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Got the other thing working as well. You have to install libpam-mount.
After that add the following line to /etc/pam.d/common-session

```
session optional            pam_mount.so
```

Theres a config file for the mounts: /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">

<pam_mount>

    <debug enable="0" />

    <mntoptions deny="suid,dev" />
    <mntoptions allow="*" />
    <mntoptions deny="*" />
    -->
    <mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />

    <logout wait="100000" hup="yes" term="yes" kill="no" />

    <volume options="username=%(USER)"  fstype="cifs"  server="server.domain.local"  path="User/%(USER)" mountpoint="/home/domain/%(USER)/Shares/%(DOMAIN_USER)" />

    <volume options="username=%(USER)"  fstype="cifs"  server="server.domain.local"  path="Data" mountpoint="/home/domain/%(USER)/Shares/Data" />

    <umount>umount %(MNTPT)</umount>

    <mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="false" />

</pam_mount>
```